# Impossible stacktrace? Access Violation with this=nullptr although checked for

Tags: c++, assembly, stack-trace, access-violation

I am analysing a rare-but-consistent crash in a quite complex project here and it's one of these "impossible stacktraces", meaning: on the first and second glance, everything looks alright.

The crash itself is "Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. this was nullptr.".

The code at the current frame of the stack looks like this:

```
FT6VehiclePathCheckpoint AT6Building::GetVehicleCheckpoint() const
{
    FT6VehiclePathCheckpoint targetCheckpoint = FT6VehiclePathCheckpoint();
    if (GetBusStopComponent() != nullptr)
    {
        ...
```

And the crash is in the line "if (GetBusStopComponent() != nullptr)". Function "GetBusStopComponent()" itself is an inlined getter to a member variable of the object, so it doesn't show up in the trace. Also, in the memory dump, "this" is indeed 0. So far so good.

However, the stack frame directly above it looks like this:

```
const AT6Building* portalBuildingByLocation = pathFinder != nullptr ? pathFinder->GetPortalBuildingByLocation(startLocation) : GetNearestDrivewayBuilding();

if (portalBuildingByLocation != nullptr)
{
    startCheckpoint = portalBuildingByLocation->GetVehicleCheckpoint();
}
```

(pointing to the line "portalBuildingByLocation->GetVehicleCheckpoint"). So clearly, there *is* a nullptr-check before calling the function. That was the first glance ^^.

Next I suspected some memory corruption inside the "GetVehicleCheckpoint" that messed up the stack trace? But there is not really anything there. The "FT6VehiclePathCheckpoint" initialization doesn't even has a constructor - just a bunch of direct initialized fields (which all are like nullptr and integer literals)..

The code was compiled with cl.exe, with optimizations turned on, so I suspect I got some UB somewhere and the compiler was relying on something...

So although I am rather a noob when it comes to reading assembly code, I tried. This is the disassembled first part of the GetVehicleCheckpoint function:

```
FT6VehiclePathCheckpoint AT6Building::GetVehicleCheckpoint() const
{
00007FF7304714B0  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx  
00007FF7304714B5  mov         qword ptr [rsp+10h],rsi  
00007FF7304714BA  push        rdi  
00007FF7304714BB  sub         rsp,40h  
    FT6VehiclePathCheckpoint targetCheckpoint = FT6VehiclePathCheckpoint();
00007FF7304714BF  xor         eax,eax  
00007FF7304714C1  mov         qword ptr [rsp+28h],0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh  
00007FF7304714CA  mov         qword ptr [rsp+30h],rax  
00007FF7304714CF  mov         rsi,rcx  

    if (GetBusStopComponent() != nullptr)
00007FF7304714D2  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx+5F8h]
```

with the crash in the last line. Ok, if I get this correctly, its trying to read a qword from rcx+5F8h and likely rcx was 0? (But if so, shouldn't the error be "access violation, trying to read from 0x5f8" instead? Well, maybe visual studio wanted to be more helpful..).

Also, I verified and yes: the BusStopComponent is indeed at offset 0x5F8 of the class..

Ok, so I tried to trace rcx to the second-to-last stackframe:

```
            const AT6Building* portalBuildingByLocation = pathFinder != nullptr ? pathFinder->GetPortalBuildingByLocation(startLocation) : GetNearestDrivewayBuilding();
00007FF730410F21  lea         rdx,[rbp-29h]  
00007FF730410F25  mov         rcx,r12  
00007FF730410F28  call        AT6AStarPathfinder::GetPortalBuildingByLocation (07FF73059CD30h)  
00007FF730410F2D  jmp         UT6Agent::HandleAgentArrivedToUseCar+34Ah (07FF730410F4Ah)  
00007FF730410F2F  test        r12,r12  
00007FF730410F32  je          UT6Agent::HandleAgentArrivedToUseCar+342h (07FF730410F42h)  
00007FF730410F34  lea         rdx,[rbp-29h]  
00007FF730410F38  mov         rcx,r12  
00007FF730410F3B  call        AT6AStarPathfinder::GetPortalBuildingByLocation (07FF73059CD30h)  
00007FF730410F40  jmp         UT6Agent::HandleAgentArrivedToUseCar+34Ah (07FF730410F4Ah)  
00007FF730410F42  mov         rcx,rsi  
00007FF730410F45  call        UT6Agent::GetNearestDrivewayBuilding (07FF73040DA50h)  

            if (portalBuildingByLocation != nullptr)
00007FF730410F4A  test        rax,rax  
00007FF730410F4D  je          UT6Agent::HandleAgentArrivedToUseCar+36Ch (07FF730410F6Ch)  
            {
                startCheckpoint = portalBuildingByLocation->GetVehicleCheckpoint();
00007FF730410F4F  mov         rcx,rax  
00007FF730410F52  lea         rdx,[rbp-9]  
00007FF730410F56  call        AT6Building::GetVehicleCheckpoint (07FF7304714B0h)  
00007FF730410F5B  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rax]
```

Again: I am not really confident in interpreting the assembly, but from just eyeballing, I see that rcx is set to whatever is in rax and rax is tested to 0 correctly. So no fancy "the compiler removed the nullptr check as optimization" is going on.

Any insights what could have caused the access violation then? Anything suspicious that could give me a lead?

Cheers, Imi.

Comment: hm.. Theory: could it be that the call to GetNearestDrivewayBuilding scrambled up the return address of its stack frame and "hoped" over the nullptr-check just right into calling to GetVehicleCheckpoint?

Comment: If this is Visual Studio, you should be able to see the register values (there's a Debug window for them).  rcx and rsi might be interesting.  Opening up a memory window for address rcx or rcx+5F8h might also be informative, as you could check out all the member variables for the class.  Checking them all one by one is probably not productive (given that there's 5f8h bytes worth), but looking to see if it seems generally correct, especially around the 5f8h offset.

Comment: RCX is indeed 0. In the second stackframe, RSI is 0x229239886E0 (in the lowest stackframe, after the "mov rsi,rcx", RSI is 0 too). But this memory location seems not to be part of the crash dump :( - I get all ?? when viewing this directly in memory debug (I assume that's because the outer "this" is located on the heap and its a "small crash dump"?). Or are values in RSI an offset to some other value?

Comment: Huh.  I'm not seeing it either.  When you walk up the stack, is it showing `movups` at F5B as the return point?  Is GetVehicleCheckpoint called from anywhere else in that routine?  You said it's optimized code, so I'm looking for some kind of jump to 07FF730410F4F nearby.

Comment: Yes, the movups at F5B is the return point of the second stack frame. Also, yes: GetVehicleCheckpoint is called two more times in other if-branches (the code is a big if/else if/else construct that all lead to GetVehicleCheckpoint on different objects).

Comment: This is the source around the issue: https://pastebin.com/Wtxtk82P and this is its disassembly https://pastebin.com/DfeBNHdv. Seems like one of the GetVehicleCheckpoint calls got inline? huh?

Comment: wait.. what? No, not inlined... you were right! They all just jump to 7FF730410F52 which is the one call to GetVehicleCheckpoint! So that means its not clear, whether I was actually in that specific branch! :)  THAT is a new lead. horay!

Comment: For example what if `RelatedPathBuildings[CurrentPath.CurrentSegmentIndex]` is null?  And while I've never done so, it seems like you should be able to do `if (this == nullptr) __debugbreak();` inside GetVehicleCheckpoint.  Catching the problem early might let you see more before things get overwritten.

Comment: "you should be able to do if (this == nullptr) __debugbreak();" -- oh,yea.. I'd love to be able to life-reproduce and debug that one. Unfortunately, it happens quite rarely out in the field, it never happened in my own builds here and I only get the stack dumps to look at.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: IIRC, calling a member function on a `nullptr` is unfortunately UB, so compilers are allowed to assume it's non-null and optimize away that check, and do so in practice.  In a non-optimized build you might get away with it for debugging, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes Then this one should do the trick? `[this]()__declspec(noinline){ if (this == nullptr) __debugbreak(); }();`

Answer (score 2):

Gotcha! (or rather David Wohlferd found it).

The "stack frame directly above" was misleading, as the code was re-using this call multiple times in the same function (in different if-branches). When looking at the local variables, the branch-path there was actual impossible and I identified the issue as being a nullptr in another array.

Thanks to David Wohlferd! Dead-on! :)